# Recalibrating \hline vertical spacing to that of \cline

Tags: tables

How do I alter the spacing dimensions of `\hline` so as to replicate those of `\cline`?

I have drawn a series of (empty-celled) tables using `\hline` for lines spanning whole tables and, e.g., `\cline{1-2}` for lines spanning just one column.  Much later, realizing that I need to overlay them, I can now see that `\hline` adds to the total row height in a way that `\cline` does not.

(For instance, look at the superposed tables below.  Within each pair, the one on the left has two internal horizontal lines, the one of the left none.  The pair on the left use `\hline` and the top and bottom lines fail to align.  The pair on the right align properly (I think) and use `\cline`.

[image] )

(The alternative is going through my document, changing `\hline` to `\cline{1-1}`, `\cline{1-2}`, or `\cline{1-3}` on a case-by-case basis.  Tedious.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline 
 \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%
\hspace{\tabcolsep}%
\llap{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline 
 \\
  \\
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
%
\quad
%
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\cline{1-1}
 \\ \cline{1-1}
  \\ \cline{1-1}
   \\ \cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}
%
\hspace{\tabcolsep}%
\llap{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\cline{1-1}
 \\ 
  \\ 
   \\ \cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mis-match comes beacuse of two lines in the middle. They add to the height. You can compensate to them in the second table using `\extrarowheight` from `array` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|}

\hline
 \\ \hline
  \\ \hline
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%
\hspace{\tabcolsep}%
{\extrarowheight=0.6\arrayrulewidth   %%% <<-- this one within a group, adjust suitably
\llap{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
 \\
  \\
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
}
%
\quad
%
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\cline{1-1}
 \\ \cline{1-1}
  \\ \cline{1-1}
   \\ \cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}
%
\hspace{\tabcolsep}%
\llap{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\cline{1-1}
 \\
  \\
   \\ \cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also do it manually, row-wise by adding `\\[\arrayrulewidth]` like in

```
\hspace{\tabcolsep}%
%{\extrarowheight=0.6\arrayrulewidth   %%% <<-- this one within a group
\llap{
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
 \\[\arrayrulewidth]
  \\[\arrayrulewidth]
   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

`\extrarowheight` approach can be approximate while adding space row-wise is accurate.

Comment: I don't know why `\cline` doesn't add that space though.

Comment: `\cline` adds no space so that `\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}` line up, even though each is technically a separate row of the underlying halign, the negative spacing keeps them on the same visible line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the information. That is really good. :-)